# Android App development targeting multiple version ie 1.x, 2.x.x, 3.x.x, 4.x.x

Tags: android

I'm new to android, i have been practicing to develop an app targeting a 2.2 version, i need help on how i can span my app to target also the other versions that is 1.x, 2.3.x, 3.x, and 4.x.x, and also some best practices when targeting screen resolutions, please help me out, thanks

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you can read the [development considerations](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html#considerations) for multiple platforms. Also checkout the [official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for supporting multiple screens.

Answer (score 0):

your app is available for every device whichs taget is higher than the app target

you have to add this into the Androidmanifest to target screnn resulutions

```
<supports-screens
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:anyDensity="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean Android Backward Compatible feature when create new project.  Google supports some libraries that you can backport the UI from version 4.x to 2.xx. You can read the guide [Backward-compatible-ui](http://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui/index.html) [Providing backwards compatibility with the android support package](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/part_4_-_providing_backwards_compatibility_with_the_android_support_package)